# Magento doesn't show full product name

Tags: php, magento, product, display

I have a webshop with a product view. 
when users are logged **out**, the product name isn't fully displayed.

[image: No full name]

But when users are logged **in**, it displays the name correctly.

[image: Full name (how it should be).]

Edit: When users are logged out, I've a module called quickview. But I can't configure anything in the backend regarding to character length.

Can someone tell me how this can happen? And how to solve this?

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: did you inspect into console title wrapper when you are not logged-in? i'm assuming just a CSS problem there (span/div with not enough width).

Comment: No, but i've inspected the h2 product-name. And it contains the whole product name, but it's not displaying it. I retyped the product name (from inspect element), And now it is showing, without making changes to the css.

Comment: is there a live (public version) of the website?

Comment: No only a dev environment unfortunately.

Comment: it's hard to help in this case. however, inspect H2 wrapper (not h2 itself) of product name and check his own css.

Comment: Already did that. Don't find anything and I'm in doubt if it's a stylesheet issue...

Answer (score -1):

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
        //Your Product FullName
    }else{
        //Your Product Short Name
    }
```

//  i think this code is applied on your view.phtml file

Comment: No it isn't. can't find any character lengths. Found the solution. my product view block was a few px smaller when the customer was logged out. Made it a bit bigger and now it's showing correctly.